# How do I make an inline @link to another class in Apigen?

Tags: php, apigen

I'm trying to create a @link from one method to another method in a different class. Example:

```
class Bar extends Foo
{
    /** 
    * This link works: {@link barFunction()} 
    * This link also works: {@link fooFunction()}
    * This link doesn't work: {@link Foo::fooFunction()}
    */
    public function fooFunction()
    {

    }

    /**
    * Bar function is another function
    */
    public function barFunction()
    {

    }
}
```

The inline @link within the same class works OK. But the inline link to another class does not generate a link to the documentation. Instead, it generates:

```
<a href="Foo::fooFunction()">Foo::fooFunction()</a>
```

Am I doing something wrong or am I simply trying to achieve what is not possible? I looked over Apigen documentation and their forums (both at GitHub and Google Groups) but without any success. Thanks for your help.